# Hammer JS Tap and Press on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, gesture, hammer.js

I'm trying to build the following for mobile browsers: I have a row of boxes. Each box holds additional information underneath and a href to another website. When I scroll the page via a certain box or just taphold it, i want to show the additional information. If I tap it, i want to go to the href.

I've built a solution with click, touchstart and touchend, which worked, but quite buggy, because **click** and **touchstart** are interfering (I guess). So I'm hoping to build a more solid version with hammer.js. My Idea of the event handling:

- On touch start : The additional Information ist Shown.
- If I release until 250ms: The Touch is counted as a tap and I'm sent to the href.
- After 251ms: It's defenitely a taphold
- On scrolling/touch move: It's defenitely a taphold

That's the js i have until now. I changed the starting point of the **press** time to 1ms and the threshold to 1000px to be able to scroll. **pressup** doesnt trigger if i press and scroll. I think pan is triggering instead? How can I change the settings of pressup?

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

mc.add(new Hammer.Press({
    event: 'press',
    pointer: 1,
    threshold: 1000,
    time: 1,
}));

mc.on('press', function(event) {
  $('.skills').addClass( "show" );
});

mc.on('pressup', function(event) {
$('.skills').removeClass( "show" );
});
```

I've built a codepen (or where should i post it for mobile testing?)
http://codepen.io/Vin-ni/pen/JXYMXm

So I need two things to happen. **Pressup** needs to trigger and on **Pressup** i need to check if the time since **press** is more or less than 250ms.

it would be something like

```
mc.on('pressup', function(event) {
$('.skills').removeClass( "show" );
     if (time since press < 251ms) {
     window.location.href = (this).data(link);
     }
});
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution (It binds the event to each div in a grid):

```
$('.class').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var mc = new Hammer.Manager(this);

    mc.add( new Hammer.Tap() );

    //customize Press event to trigger instantly + 1000px scrollable
    mc.add(new Hammer.Press({
        event: 'press',
        pointer: 1,
        threshold: 1000,
        time: 1,
    }));


    mc.on('press tap', function(event) {
        //do stuff
        if (event.type == "tap") {
            window.location.href = link;
            $('.skills').removeClass( "show" );
        }   
    });

    mc.on('pressup', function(event) {
    //undo stuff
    });

});
```